# How to derive "elementary particle field quanta" from "2d string theory world sheets"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory

I was hoping to see a mathematical and logical derivation:

> How to derive elementary particle field quanta (0d creation or annihilation operators) from 2d string theory world sheets? (or do we require not just the  world sheets, but also the background spacetime as an input?

Previously I asked a related question but I did not learn such a derivation from the previous posts.

Comment: Which related question?

Comment: The answer to your question is to be found in the first few chapters of any introductory text book on string theory. At least the principle of how that works. Is that not sufficient for you? Or do you want mode detailed string theory phenomenology?